# Output values of neural network become different with same training data and test data in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I built a neural network model in Tensorflow (Python3.5).

But whenever I initialize the model and re-train with the same training data, the output values of a specific input is always different. It means, models trained with same parameters and data but initialized differently predict the far different result. I think that if I train with the same parameters and data, the weights and biases will become almost same regardless of initializing.

I changed the number of hidden layers, learning rate, activation function, and batch size, but this problem was unchanged. What should I do in this situation?

My model is using

**25 normalized inputs** which each elements are in range of [-1,1]
**32 hidden layers** (1-level)
**10 output layers** (I expected each output value should be in [-1, 1] because I trained with reward which is in [-1,1].)
**xavier initializer**
**learning rate = 0.00001** (I reduced it from 0.001 to 0.00001 recently.)
**tanh function** for activation function
**843,844 training data** (Is it too small..?)
batch size is **32** and queue size is **256** (random sampling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how long you train the net for, and even then, it's possible to have some mismatches.

Have you tracked the performance of your model in general?
Has you model even converged?
You should integrate the [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard) into your model to see these things.

If your model has not converged (i.e. you didn't train long enough), or it just has bad performance in general, you have your answer.

If on the the other hand your model performs well (which I do not think from how your question sounds), and it has converged at say 80% accuracy,
it's still possible to get different values. 
This comes from the fact that 80% accuracy means 80% over **all** data you tested it on, not an individual data point. So it might get Data point A correct and point B wrong on the first try, but on the second try both of them are switched, but you still have the same accuracy.